# Visual Studio Shortcut for building all T4 in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just upgraded my VS2012 Proff to Ultimate and lost some settings. One I lost I can't find anywhere. It is a button I which builds all T4s in the solution. Anyone have an idéa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming it's somehow disappeared from the Build menu.

1. Right-click a toolbar or the menu bar and go to Customize.
2. Choose the Commands tab
3. Select Menu bar = "Build"
4. Press "Add Command"
5. Under Category "Build" you should see "Transform all T4 Templates"
6. Click ok to add it back to the build menu
7. [Optional] Move it up or down to where you want
8. Click close

The command should also be on the Build toolbar - you may need to do Add Or Remove Buttons or Customize to get it to come back. You can follow the same steps as above but instead choose Toolbar = "Build" in step 3.

Comment: Great info. I use T4MVC and was able to setup a keyboard shortcut (CTRL+4, CTRL+4) to update all my templates now. Thanks!